# pycharm auto indentation settings

Tags: pycharm

I'm using PyCharm 2016.2.1 and when I try to enter a new line, it doesn't insert tab in it.

for example like this.

```
for x in range(5):
print('hello')
```

How can I change my PyCharm to indent? I've tried 'smart tabs', 'use tab characters' and so on but I can't fix it.

Comment: I am having the same problem, but for inserting spaces instead of tabs. I think this is a bug in pycharm.

Answer (score 2):

The 'use tab character' is here so that you can use the tab character (\t) instead of just a sequence of spaces for your indentation.

In File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > Python > Tabs and Indents, check your indent size value is not zero. If so, change it to 4 (recommended by PEP8) or to the length you want your indent to be.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately the question clearly said that they had tried 'use tab character' and it didn't work, so explaining what it is intended to do is probably not very helpful.

Comment: Sorry about that. I did read the question carefully, I just thought it might be helpful to know why it did not work.